# Spinner Shortform of selected item

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know is it possible after selecting in a spinner an item to show a shortform of the selecteditem?

for example: Selected Item = "Wuhuhu Base" should show shortform "WB"

regards Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter for your spinner, override getDropDownView and getView. You also need two data source, one is full length, one is short. You can look at my example

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    text.setText(dataFull[position]);
    return row;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    text.setText(dataShort[position]);
    return row;
}
```